# Replace every value in pandas.DataFrame row with the count of that value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replace the values in my `pd.DataFrame`, `df` with counts of the value in row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'foo': [3,3,1,1,1,2],
  'bar': [4,4,1,3,3,3]
}).transpose()
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| bar | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I would expect to see:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| bar | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Unable to determine a solution using `.apply()`.

What is the most sensible way of achieving the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.value_counts` with `map`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5
foo  2  2  3  3  3  1
bar  2  2  1  3  3  3
```